# Not unique table/alias in mysql while joining from different database

Tags: mysql, vtiger

I get the error [Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'vtiger_leadscf'

```
UPDATE vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_leadaddress ON vtiger_new.vtiger_leadaddress.leadaddressid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_users ON vtiger_new.vtiger_users.id = vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid
JOIN vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf ON vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
SET vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.cf_953 = CONCAT(vtiger_new.vtiger_users.first_name,' ',vtiger_new.vtiger_users.last_name)
WHERE vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
AND cf_953 = ""
```

can't figure out whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last join and update reference the same table.
Use  `JOIN table AS other_name` to avoid this problem.

Here is the corrected query.
Plus I think you meant vtiger_new on the last join and not vtigerdb as you wrote.

```
UPDATE vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_leadaddress ON vtiger_new.vtiger_leadaddress.leadaddressid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf.leadid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_users ON vtiger_new.vtiger_users.id = vtiger_new.vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid
JOIN vtiger_new.vtiger_leadscf AS vlead ON vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vlead.leadid
SET vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.cf_953 = CONCAT(vtiger_new.vtiger_users.first_name,' ',vtiger_new.vtiger_users.last_name)
WHERE vtigerdb.vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vlead.leadid
AND cf_953 = ""
```